# zsh: "reload:4 = not found" for function named "reload"

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I'm trying to make a shortcut for myself to reload a site on a server, so I'm getting the site name via regex, and then trying to have zsh run a command to reload with the correct parameters.

I've tried numerous variations on this but I keep getting the error "= not found" which I don't understand.

```
function reload(){
    pwd=$(pwd) 
    [[ $pwd =~ .*\/custom\/.+\/(.+)(\/stage)? ]] && echo "$match[1]"
    read -q "REPLY?rc $match[1].stage reload"
    if[REPLY == ""] then
    cmd="rc $match[1].stage reload"
    $=cmd
}
```

Everything works until the last 1-2 lines.

Output expected:
`rc somesite.stage reload // then enter runs this command in zsh`

Actual output:

```
$ currentDir % reload  
currentDirSiteName
rc currentDirSiteName.stage reload
reload:4: = not found
```

Comment: Please consider testing each line by itself until you know it works fully. For example,`if[REPLY == ""] then` itself has four different syntax errors: missing space around [, around ], no `$` on the variable, and no `;` before the `then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain the error message:

You have the line

```
if[REPLY == ""] then
```

According to the parsing rules of zsh, a line such as `A B C` is broken on the spaces (with respect to quoting, of course), and the first word (i.e. `A`) is taken as a command to execute, while the other words are the parameters. In your case, breaking on the spaces yields the 4 words

```
if[REPLY
==
""]
then
```

First, we see that you most likely don't have a command named `if[REPLY`. This by itself would already be an error, but zsh bails out earlier: Before it can even try to run the command, it has to prepare the parameters:

The first parameter is `==`, and parameters starting with an `=` sign undergo special expansion in zsh: For a word `=foo`, the shell tries to locate an executable named `foo` and replaces the word by the absolute path to this executable. You can try this out by typing `echo =cat`, which will output something like */usr/bin/cat*. In your case, what follows after the `=` sign, is another `=` sign. zsh therefore tries to find a program named `=` in your path, and is unsuccessful with it. This is the cause of the error message.

If you had written instead

```
if [[ $REPLY == "" ]]; then
```

the shell would have recognized that you have an `if` (which is a syntactic construct). After the `if`, it expects a command. `[[ ... ]]` is an internal command for evaluating certain types of expressions, and inside this construct, different parsing rules apply. For this reason, `==` does not undergo the expansion process described before, but is understood as an operator for testing equality.

BTW, A more idiomatic way would be to write

```
if [[ -z $REPLY ]]; then
```

Comment: Thank you for that comprehensive answer!